# Avoiding printing of duplicates in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have one array list contains object( id,name).need to remove if duplicate names in the list

I need to print only name once if it is repeating

Comment: I can't read bold letters. And now I don't see any question there.

Comment: Add to a Set with an appropriate comparator

Comment: show your code that have been tried

Comment: When the title of your question is longer than your body, chances are you're a.) putting too much info into your title **and** b.) don't have enough information in your body.

Answer (score 3):

Use SET if you want don't want duplicate entries in your list:

1. **HashSet** if you don't required sequence
2. **LinkedHashSet** if you need to print name in sequence

**Note**: You must override equals and hashcode in object(ID,Name) otherwise you will find duplicate object in SET

Comment: thanks...i have used set to remove the repeated value ..its works fine now

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean checkDuplicate(ArrayList list) {
 HashSet set = new HashSet();
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  boolean val = set.add(list.get(i));
  if (val == false) {
    return val;
  }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `java.util.Set` instead. It cannot contain duplicates.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

```
Set<String> myNames = new HashSet<String>();
myNames.add("JAMES");
myNames.add("ELLA");
myNames.add("JAMES");

myNames.size() // will return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set data structure with implementing appropriate Comparator. Run a loop and put your objects in that set. Print this set.

Answer (score 0):

Arraylist provides an iterator that allows to delete the last element returned by the iterator from the list itself. So we just keep track of the names that we've already seen. A `Set` implementation is helpful.

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
Iterator<MyType> it = getListFromSomewhere().iterator();  // you know how
while(it.hasNext()) {
   if (!names.add(it.next().getName()) {
     it.remove();
   }
}
```

Hint: adding to a set returns false, if the value is already in the set.

*Remarks*

Your requirement wasn't that clear: here we keep the *first* entry with a name and delete all *following* entries from the list. If the list is not sorted by id, then it is rather random, which entries are kept an which are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of **Set** as well as **List** family

We have seen how to remove duplicates with **Set** family. We can do it with the help of **List** family as well. Please refer below code.

```
package com.rais.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Rais.Alam
 * @project Utils
 * @date Dec 18, 2012
 */
public class ConverterUtil
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        List<String> original = new ArrayList<String>();

        original.add("Tomcat");
        original.add("Jboss");
        original.add("GlassFish");
        original.add("Weblogic");
        original.add("Tomcat");

        List<String> newList = removeDuplicates(original);

        for (String value : newList)
        {
            System.out.println(value);
        }

    }

    public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> original)
    {

        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String value : original)
        {
            if (!tempList.contains(value))
            {
                tempList.add(value);
            }
        }

        return tempList;

    }

}
```